# T sql with finding data with out CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Create Table hospital
(
     Id INT Identity(1,1),
     HospitalName Varchar(50),
     ExternalID INT Primary Key
)
GO

Create table Doctor
(
    ID Int Identity(1,1), 
    Doctorname Varchar(100), 
    Active Char(1), 
    InternalID INT
)
go

ALTER TABLE Doctor ADD FOREIGN KEY (InternalID)
REFERENCES Hospital (ExternalID)
go

INSERT INTO hospital (HospitalName, ExternalID)
VALUES ('Innova', 1), ('Reston', 2), ('Fairfax', 3)
go

INSERT INTO Doctor (Doctorname, Active, InternalID)
VALUES('Nick', 'A', 1), ('Nathan', 'D', 1), ('Dean', 'D', 1), ('Rick', 'D', 2), ('Tony', 'D', 2), ('Bob', 'D', 2), ('Sugar', 'A', 3), ('Shrek', 'A', 3)
go

select * from hospital
Select * from Doctor
GO
```

- `D` stands for Deactivated
- `A` stands for Active
- In a hospital, IF any 1 doctor is active I want `Yes` to be displayed
- In a hospital, IF all doctors are deactivated then `N` to be displayed

Due to the nature of my query I cannot use CTE's

Please provide any simple script

Comment: Please edit your question and (1) explain what you are trying to do.  (Hint:  questions should have questions.)  (2) Sample data *and* desired results are helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select h.HospitalName 
, case when max(d.Id) is null then 'N' else 'Yes' end ActiveDoctorInHospital
from hospital h
left outer join doctor d
on d.InternalId = h.ExternalId
and d.Active = 'A'
group by h.id, h.HospitalName
```

Comment: Thats was fast and helpful  JohnlBevan

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `case` statement and `exists`:

```
select h.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from doctor d
                          where d.internalid = h.externalid and d.active = 'A'
                         )
             then 'Yes' else 'N'
        end)
from hospital h;
```